# Typing a URL http address in Firefox will auto redirect to HTTPS

Tags: apache, google-chrome, firefox, nginx

I have this minor but annoying problem in Firefox.

I have one server with two web server instances:

1. **nginx web server that will auto redirect to HTTPS**
2. **built in web server in Rocket.Chat messaging platform**.

The Rocket.Chat's built-in web server will accept connections at this port: 8818. Accessing first the Rocket.Chat's web server at port 8818 is fine(http://ip-server:8818). But after when I type the http://ip-server/, it will naturally redirect to https://ip-server as expected because nginx was configured to redirect 80 traffic to 443(https), the problem is whenever I will go first with the https site (https://ip-server), going with http://ip-server:8818 will force the browser to redirect to https://ip-server:8818 making my install of Rocket.Chat no longer accessible. It can be partially fixed by clearing history, and then I'll go first with the http://ip-server:8818. I am force to isolate the two instances to temporarily fix this issue, one in a private window and the other in a normal session.

I also find out that this is also the case when browsing with Google Chrome. Have any of you with the idea how to fix this? I think because this is common to both browsers, I must configure the server side of things(Nginx or the Rocket.Chat).

I tried Changing Firefox's browser.urlbar.autoFill to false in about:config to no avail.

Thanks,
Allan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all confirm it is HSTS:

Look at the headers returned (either in developer tools or by using a tool like [securityheaders.io](https://securityheaders.io/)). If you see a Strict-Transport-Security header then it is that.

Assuming it is, then you need to turn this off at the server level. For Chrome you can just change your server config, turn it off, and then visit chrome://net-internals/#hsts and delete the HSTS policy for that domain.

For FireFox and other browsers it's not as easy, as they don't have a way of clearing the HSTS policy. So instead what you have to do is (which will also work for Chrome btw):

1. Find the server config, and change max-age to 0, and reload your server config.
2. Load the https site in your browser to load this new policy (which immediately expires).
3. Remove the server config completely, and then reload the config again.
4. You should now be able to visit the site in HTTP.

Any reason why you don't want chat over HTTPS anyway?

Comment: ssllabs says:Strict Transport Security (HSTS)  No

Comment: It works in Google Chrome as you per your tips. chrome://net-internals/#hsts, however this is a configuration nightmare if I have 10s or hundreds of google chrome installs. Anyway, I will try the server side. Regarding your question, I need http and https from that server. One is at port 8818 and the other which is https is port 80. I think to remove this problem, I need LXD container for both.

Comment: If that works then guess it must have been on at some point (maybe someone was experimenting with it?) or it could be set on some pages but not others (but this affects whole domain), or on a higher domain with includeSubDomain. And yes it could be a configuration nightmare which I've been trying to warn about for a bit now: https://www.tunetheweb.com/blog/dangerous-web-security-features/

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you have HSTS enabled and that is how it works.
HSTS works for whole host regardless of ports. So as soon as your browser get HSTS header from `https://some-host` it will apply `http` to `https` redirect to any request to that `some-host` with any `port` part.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797

At the end of introduction

> This specification also incorporates notions from [JacksonBarth2008]
> in that policy is applied on an "entire-host" basis: it applies to
> HTTP (only) over **any TCP port** of the issuing host.

Comment: Therefore, there is no easy way to disable HSTS for only specific sites or cases such as in my situation as indicated in this firefox post: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/942924